# Hammerhead dragon craving for seafood

Tags: evolution, creature-design, dragons

How can I explain a female adult dragon standing at 30 to 32 meters living on the peaks of a snowy mountain, will dive and swim hundreds of miles into the ocean to hunt for sperm whales and colossal squids and bring them back to its nest where its hungry young are waiting? what kinds of evolutionary traits does this particular species of dragon possess in order to fish for food in the abyss?

Note: Kindly state in your answer how does the dragon overcome baro-trauma or decompression sickness, most importantly also include abilities that enable the hammerhead dragon (not to be confused with hammerhead shark) to "see" its prey while submerged. It uses its "mantis claws" to stun its prey by generating high temperature from collapsing vacuum in the water to produce powerful shock-wave to KO its opponents. Its detachable tail acts as a lure to bait potential colossal squid by wriggling and the vibration is so powerful its mimic the low frequency of a sperm whale. There are colonies of bio-luminescence bacteria growing underneath its translucent scales which display brilliant colorful light to communicate to their own kinds during diving. It also has a pouch in front of its belly to store its emergency ration such as live cows and lions, and last but not least it has been shown to use its own eggs as projectiles to incapacitate its enemy when it feels threatened.

Comment: Depends on what kind of dragon you mean. Could you add an Image? Asian/European/SouthAmerican dragons look totaly different.

Comment: @Sempie it looks like leviathan from the bible however the exact genus is dragon hope it help.

Comment: Havent read the bible, but google img search showed, that Leviathan is some kind of giant snake-like dragon with wings, so basicly the asian version of a dragon. Is that correct?

Comment: @Sempie yes however please visualize the serpent comes with giant pair of bat-like wings.

Comment: Alright. How to imagine the "Hammerhead"? You wrote it's not to be confused with hammerhead shark. What else do you mean by hammerhead?

Comment: @Sempie actually I was dropping a clue regarding its sensory organ which is capable of generating minute electricity, I hoped to prevent readers from visualizing a hammerhead shark with fins and wings. My apology for misleading the readers.

Comment: What kind of mother would throw it's own babys at enemies? Lold more than I should have.

Comment: This is REALLY broad...

Comment: How is this to broad, it's pretty precise I think.

Comment: @Aify I was hoping to narrow the question by giving the readers a couple of details under the note section, however I'm most willing to provide even more informations please do not hestitate to advise me how to improve this question thanks.

Comment: When I read this question, it struck me as too broad because it seems like you're looking for a list type answer - and typically, those come as Idea generation questions, or are simply too broad. "What kinds of evolutionary traits..." definitely looks like you're looking for a list. The notes also makes it sound like you're looking for a list. (eg: "State in your answer how ..." and "include abilities that ...")

Comment: "It looks like leviathan from the bible..." The bible, being a book, doesn't have pictures, nor does it precisely describe the leviathan.

Comment: "*will dive and swim hundreds of miles into the ocean*".  The ocean isn't that deep... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short background:
In fables, dragons are generally characterised as very intelligent creatures, thus they can adapt to environmental change better than other species.
In some stories they live in caves, in others on mountains with a nest like (giant) eagles.
Yours is seemingly the latter.

**Why should an animal nest at such an remote location?**
Simple: safety.
Dragons are an extremely dangerous animal and thus human will try to kill the brood before they become a threat. Nesting at the highest heights provides excellent safety, because the dangerous human has to take a high risk while climbing the mountain. Climbing mountains is dangerous in any case, but with a mother dragon that notices the climber, it's suicide. Climbing takes considerable time in which the mother dragon can notice the human(s) and repel the danger.

**Why to hunt in deep sea?**
Your dragon is larger than a bus. This means it needs a lot of food. A deer is more of a little snack than a meal and hunting in a forest is near to impossible for such a large creature. In open fields ( stealing humans' cattle ) it's dangerous, because the humans might figure out how to kill a dragon. Humans are highly intelligent in organizing as a group, using tools and weapons. AVOID!

Also, lizards and snakes ( Dragons are in the same biological family I would assume. ) need to rest after a larger meal; they cannot travel far for, at least, some hours. So it would be best if the prey could be brought to the nest to be eaten there.

But gathering 10 larger animals on land, like cows, bears or deer, would take the whole day. Better to find something bigger. If there are no rhinos or elephants, search has to be under water.

A group of white shark or tiger shark is a dangerous threat, even a large dragon could receive capital wounds which is critical for every predator.
A predator that cannot hunt (due to the wounds) will starve. The Mantis-Claw technique of your dragon focuses on individual prey, not groups.

Sperm wale and giant squids are both more dangerous than a white shark, but single individuals, not groups. For both, the right technique should be chosen. (However, there should be large prey near the surface, like orca, blue whale, whale shark and so on).

**The pros of "hammerhead".**
Same as the hammerhead shark, the dragon has a larger range of sensory perception and has a better 3D perception over long range. (Triangulation)
Also, it's easier to look beside corners and over cliffs without being seen, if you only have to show a little part of your hammerhead, not the entire head.

**Barotrauma**
Some fish deal with this problem with their air-bladder. 
Your dragon could have a hollow organ in which it could produce different pressures by producing specific gas. This hollow organ could be the lung, but then, the lung has to be very tough to not end in a pneumothorax then.

Comment: I'll colate more answers if you don't mind and I enjoyed fables a lot.

Comment: I've made a few edits to your post. If you disagree, feel free to roll them back.

Answer (score 1):

Generally animals, including predators, tend to 'nest' with in a reasonably close distance to their food source.

So a dragon nesting in mountain heights and getting its primary food from the ocean could cause some problems, especially since it appears the dragon swims into the deeps looking for it's food.

Since the nesting is on mountain tops, I would imagine that deep sea fishing came later in its evolution, since except for a few examples, high quality flying and high quality swimming (both needed, takes a good swimmer to catch a whale or squid, and then fly it up to the top of a mountain).  Loons are one good example of both qualities.

Obviously, being able to hold their breath for long periods would be important.  Many dragons have frills and armor plating, the hammerhead would need to be very smooth, more like a newt, streamlined.  Drag in the air is bad enough, swimming miles upon miles trying to catch quick prey designed for it's environment, will need an equally designed predator.  It's wings would have to act much more like fins, a loon's wings are placed farther back on its body.

I find the 'detachable tail' to be a little far fetched.  Tails on a dragon are huge, and require a lot of energy to generate.  It is an important tool in both swimming and flying and loosing a large part of it trying to attract prey seems a little extreme.

A whale hunting dragon could do most of its hunting from the air and save a lot of energy just finding a pod that has surfaced and killing one of them instead of swimming around looking for one.